# Trouble setting param values in controller for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

I have a form that lets users add a new blocked tv show to their list of blocked shows. The form is not taking the param values (`:user_id`, `:title`, `:image`) that I tried to set in the controller. I'm a beginner, so I'm guessing the syntax is the problem.

Also I am getting a `Couldn't find Tvshow without Id` error when trying to use the @tvshow instance variable to set the param values of `:title` and `:image`. Each Blocked show should have the same title and image as the tvshow that the user selects in the `collection_select`. Is there an easier way to do this?

View

```
<%= form_for @blockedshow do |b| %>
<%= b.label :tvshow_id, "Add a Blocked TV Show " %><br/>
<%= collection_select(:blockedshow, :tvshow_id, Tvshow.all, :id, :title, prompt: true) %>

<%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class BlockedshowsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @blockedshow = Blockedshow.new
  end


  def create
    @tvshow = Tvshow.find params[:blockedshow][:id]
    @blockedshow = Blockedshow.new(safe_blockedshow)
      params[:user_id] = current_user.id
      params[:title] = @tvshow.title
      params[:image] = @tvshow.image

    if @blockedshow.save
      flash[:notice] = "New Blocked TV Show added successfully"
      redirect_to tv_show_index_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  private

  def safe_blockedshow
    params.require(:blockedshow).permit(:title, :user_id, :tvshow_id, :image)
  end
    end
```

Blockedshow model

```
class Blockedshow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phrases
  has_many :tvshows
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Tvshow model

```
class Tvshow < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :phrases
    belongs_to :blockedshow


    def self.search_for (query)
            where('title LIKE :query', query: "%#{query}%")
        end
end
```

Routes

```
  resources :blockedshows

  post 'blockedshows', to:'blockedshows#create#[:id]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting the issue because params[:blockedshow][:id] is not passed, if your trying to access the Tvshow id selected by from the drop-list you can do the following

> @tvshow = Tvshow.find params[:blockedshow][:tvshow_id]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have the `:tvshow_id` input working but `:user_id`, `:title`, and `:image` are still showing blank in the database.

Comment: you can merge the params before calling the safe_blockedshow()     

 `@tvshow = Tvshow.find params[:blockedshow][:id]`


`params.merge!(user_id: current_user.id, title: @tvshow.title, image: @tvshow.image)`

`@blockedshow = Blockedshow.new(safe_blockedshow)`

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed by changing the controller to this:

```
 def create
    @tvshow = Tvshow.find params[:blockedshow][:tvshow_id]
    @blockedshow = Blockedshow.new(
        :user_id =>current_user.id,
        :title=> @tvshow.title,
        :image=> @tvshow.image,
        :tvshow_id=>@tvshow.id
    )
```